# Logging into vBulletin 4.0 via python

Tags: python, vbulletin

I am trying to login to a vBulletin  4.0 site using python. This is my code:

```
import cookielib
import urllib2
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : 'user', 'j_password: 'password'})
opener.open('http://www.example.com/forum/login.php?do=login', login_data)
```

I don't understand how to receive the necessary stuff back to know whether I logged in or not though, how would I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Error added. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the error message says it all... Are you definitely sure the URL is the correct target for the forms action?

Comment: Well, I am pretty sure. That's kind of what I am asking though. :3

Comment: Is it normally on `http://www.example.com/forum/login.php?do=login` ?

Comment: No, I just put it in so as to not disclose the info.

Comment: I meant... it seems really unlikely the .php to be on the root of the domain... hence... is `forum` or other required in the path...

Comment: Ah, thanks. I rechecked and it is /forum/login.php

Comment: However, do any of you have any ideas how test whether login was succesful?

Comment: You'd probably not get a 200 if it wasn't, or you check the page for "error" or whatever makes sense... (check for presence of cookies even)... not sure... that'd be another question... Just do the process manually and use firebug/chrome dev tools to watch the network activity...

Comment: Yeah, I tried. It shows loads of stuff, don't know how to get it within python though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest using python requests module.

With it you can forget about the the nuance and annoyances of urllib.

So your code would reduce to something along the lines of:

```
import requests

params = {'username' : 'user', 'j_password: 'password'}

r = requests.get('http://www.example.com/forum/login.php?do=login', params=params)

r.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: I tried this, but I seem to get no response if the password is wrong. Is there anyway just to get right or wrong from the code?

Comment: @LordArmadillo if vBulletin uses standard codes, it should return either a 401 or a 403 for auth fail, which would be caught by the method `raise_for_status()`. Can you look at the vBulletin API docs and see what code they return?

Comment: Well, I salvaged some other pieces and I got it working. Basically, I try & access a restricted page and then test whether r not that page asks me to login. Inefficient, but it works.

Comment: @LordArmadillogood to hear. Maybe there's a plug-in for vBulletin that makes it easier to auth from the API and not web-like requests.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. But - as I do not run the forum I don't want to start asking. It was more just a little interesting project. Though, I may look it up for future reference!